# Windows support software could not be saved to selected drive, Error Installing Win 10 on MBP2017. I Already did SVC, MVRAM reset

Tags: macos, bootcamp, startup, partition

I have already did SMC and NVRAM Reset, and also using first aid on my single partition drive. Still doesn't work.

1. First, **before I was used first aid, and did NVRAM- SMC reset**. The title is "Disk Could not be Partitioned"
2. Then after I did resets and first aid it was become "windows support software could not be saved to the selected drive"

I'm not sure whether Im right doing SMC and NVRAM reset or not. I've already did NVRAM reset in 20 second and in multi repetition grey-blanked screen. It already do, right ? And also SMC Reset.

3. And I did this :
   CMD S in when reboot, and then

**type command line :**
/sbin/fsck -fy
reboot
[image: I wait for the background process to finish in hope it can be partitioned and process completed]
to check... I dont know. To resolve **Disk Could not be Partitioned** issue, after I use **First Aid.**

I've already tired 4-7 times in three days. And it was very long time to wait BCA to download Windows Support Software. About 2-3 hours.

I dont know what should I do..
Thanks for the help.

[image: But failed again]

[image: Here the process when I do checking with command line after reboot, before the last time I tried (above)]

Answer (score 1):

Again after I give other shot by doing this : http://gizmostorm.com/fix-the-windows-support-software-could-not-be-saved-to-the-selected-drive-boot-camp/ said : **Can't Install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server"**. **But It works, after I give it another shot. I hope it'll help for anybody who have same issue as me. Thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

Use VPN and connect from U.S. IP address.

I am from central Europe. I dont know why, but it helped me instantly.

I guess too sensitive rules on their firewall.